# Calling the same code in multiple servlets

Tags: java, servlets, refactoring

I am using this piece of code in about 7 servlets. Does anyone know a way where I can put this piece of code in one file and then call it in my servlet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks

```
String type = request.getParameter("type");
        String outputPage;


        if("xml".equals(type)) {
            response.setContentType("text/xml");
            outputPage = "/WEB-INF/results/filmsXml.jsp";
        }
        else if("json".equals(type)) {
            response.setContentType("text/json");
            outputPage = "/WEB-INF/results/filmsJson.jsp";
        }
        else {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            outputPage = "/WEB-INF/results/filmsText.jsp";
        }
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(outputPage);
        rd.include(request, response);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can put it to a base class and make all such servlets its subclass.
2. You can put it to a separate class and call it form each servlet.
3. You can put it to a new servlet, let say `ContentTypeMappingServlet`. All servlets should dispatch not to JSP, but to this servlet. This `ContentTypeMappingServlet` will implement the common logic and dispatch to the proper JSP.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would you be able to give me any links or any examples as its something completely new and i have not done this before.

Comment: Links to what? To explanation of what a class and subclass is?

Comment: create a Util class and add this code to a public method to that util class, call this method instantiating the Util class will work